# Callout from trigger without using Future annotation

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

At this moment I'm calling a @future method X from the Account_after_update trigger. I have to use @future annotation because X makes an external site call (just to notify account is updated). It's working fine.

But for some reasons (please don't ask why) I have to remove @future annotation.
And of course it will be impossible to make HTTP request from the X method (Salesforce restriction).

Is there a way how to notify external site about account updating (and send an account ID) without using of @furure annotation? Or even without a trigger? Probably something like subscription to account_updated event.

Comment: Why do you have to remove the `future`, you can't call an async job from a Trigger so that is by design

Comment: My customer is planning to add 3rd party code that has problems with my trigger. I don't know anything about changes. I think it uses @future method to import/update accounts. So error "System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method" occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [outbound messages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm) which can send a soap request to an endpoint using workflow, or you can use the [streaming api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm) where you can create push topics to send push notifications to subscribers.  Of the two options outbound messages is simplest if your endpoint supports soap.

Comment: Theoretically, outbound messages should work. I will try this approach.

Comment: Yes, outbound message is simple solution and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating background jobs to do the work for you. [hope you find the solution here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_jobs_intro.htm)